# Entering text in a textfield and having the text go into a tableview after pressing a button

Tags: swift, uitableview, uibutton, uitextfield, textfield

have been stuck on this to do app for a few days now. So am trying to input a "to do" in the textfield. Then by clicking the save button would send that to the tableview. But unfortunately have only been able to get the textfield to print the input text with the save button. But any help is greatly appreciated. The first two "added" strings have been added to the tableView, just looking for help.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    
    //UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource
    
    
    
    var added = [String]()
    var added2: String = "";
    var added3: String = "";
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        
        added = ["dog", "dog2"];
        
       let savedToDo = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "ThingAdded")
        
        if let savedToList = savedToDo as? UITableView {
            tableView? = savedToList
         //   cells.text = savedToList
           
            
            
        }
            
        
        
        
    }
   // var added: String = "";
    
    
    
     func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        
        return added.count
    }
    

        //savedToList
    
    //var transfer = textField.text
    
     func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit deleteSlider: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        
        if deleteSlider == .delete {
            added.remove(at: indexPath.row)
            tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
        } else if deleteSlider == .insert {
            
        }
        
    }
    
   
    
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        
       let cells = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle.default, reuseIdentifier: "TDList")
        
        cells.textLabel?.text = added[indexPath.row]
        
        return cells
        
        
        
        
        
    }
    
    /* override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
       
        if segue.identifier == "doneSegue" {
            added2 = textField.text!
        }
    }
    */
    
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!
    
    

    
    
    @IBAction func saveButton(segue: UIStoryboardSegue) {
    //_ sender: Any
        
        added3 = textField.text!
        
        //textField.text! == tableView?
   //     var returns = textField.text;
        
      //  textField.text! == tableView
       
        //let additions = segue.source as! tableViewAddition
        
        
        
        
        /*   if let table = tableView {
            print(table);
        }
     */
       // performSegue(withIdentifier: "endSegue", sender: nil)
        
      // let theView = segue.source as! tableViewAddition
        
     //  added2 = theView.name
        
            // if segue.identfier == "endSegue" {
            //added3 = added2.text!
        
        
        
       // let controlled = segue.destinationViewController as! tabkeViewAddition
        
       // returns = transfer
        
        UserDefaults.standard.set(textField.text!, forKey: "ThingAdded")
        
     /*   if textField >= 1 {
            saveOutputButton.isHidden = false;
        } else {
            saveOutputButton.isHidden = true;
        }
     */
        
       /* if textField.text isEqualToString: @"" == TRUE {
            saveOutputButton setEnabled: NO
        }
        */
        
        
        
  /*      if textField.text!.isEmpty {
            saveOutputButton.isHidden = true;
        } else {
            saveOutputButton.isHidden = false;
            
        }
        
   */
        added.append(added2)
        
        
        if let field = textField.text {
            print(field);
           
            tableView?.reloadData()
            
            
        }
        
    }
    
  
    
    
    
    @IBOutlet weak var saveOutputButton: UIButton!
    
    
    

// right handed and left handed mode
     override   func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        self.view.endEditing(true);
       
    }
    

   public     func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
            textField.resignFirstResponder()
            
            return true;
        
        
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set

`tableView.delegate = self`

`tableView.dataSource = self`

I also noticed, in your `saveButton` function , you are saving the text to added3, but are adding added2 to your array. If you save the text to added3, you must add added3 to your array.

Making a To-do list app is a great way to learn the basics of tableViews and persistent data. I'd highly recommend this [tutorial video](https://youtu.be/4R9DJxjmSCk). The channel also has a lot of other videos and is a great resource for beginners to iOS and Swift.

Comment: thank you gonna take a look at the video and gonna try setting those to self :)